# update table records set a field as addition of fields in two rows conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Name: TraderCapital

Columns:

```
Trader (varchar),   
Currency(varchar),   
Date(int i.e. yyyymmdd format),    
Capital(int)
```

primary key fields: Trader, Currency

```
Trader, Currency, Date, Capital  
A, USD, 20190605, 100  
A, USD, 20190606, 100  
B, INR, 20190605, 200   
B, INR, 20190606, 200   
C, USD, 20190606, 100  
D, USD, 20190601, 100
```

I want to update my table after aggregating Capital of 20190606 on to Capital of 20190605. So, desired output should look like:

```
Trader, Currency, Date, Capital  
A, USD, 20190605, 200  
B, INR, 20190605, 400  
C, USD, 20190606, 100 
D, USD, 20190601, 100
```

Could you help me write sql query for same?

Comment: use `min(date)` and `Sum(Capital) over (partition by Trader order by date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `LAG()`. In the first step I created a column that checks if there is a previous day for a row. Later I used this column (`previousDay`) to group rows.

```
with previousDay as (
    select
        *
        ,LAG(date) over (partition by trader, currency order by date asc) as PreviousDay
    from TraderCapital
)
select
     trader
    ,currency
    ,case when PreviousDay is not null then dateadd(day, -1, date) else date end as date
    ,sum(Capital) as capital
from previousDay 
group by case when PreviousDay is not null then dateadd(day, -1, date) else date end
    ,trader
    ,currency
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to update the table records and not just to select them. I'll update my question language.

Comment: You can do it simply. Insert your table to a temporary table, delete rows that you want to 'updated' in your main table and then insert them from the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Try window functions like:

```
select b.Trader,b.Currency, b.Date, b.running_total as Capital 
from (
select a.Trader,a.Currency, a.Date, a.running_total
, row_number() over (partition by a.Trader, a.Currency order by a.running_total desc) rnk
from (
select * ,sum(capital) over (partition by Trader, Currency order by Date desc) as running_total
from TraderCapital )a )b
where b.rnk = 1
```

Test Result:

[Dd<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44ab593ea5872a34f80545f9cfff36f0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @M. Kanarkowski and @Gen Wan for your answers. Here is what worked finally for me based on your suggestions:

```
with PreviousDayTable as (  
select *, LAG(Date) over (partition by Trader, Currency order by Date) 
          as previousDay
from TraderCapital
),
TotalTable as (
select Trader, Currency, 
       case when previousDay is not null then previousDay else Date end as PreviousDay,
       sum(Capital) as agg
  from PreviousDayTable 
  group by Trader, Currency,
           case when previousDay is not null then previousDay else Date end
)
update TraderCapital 
set TraderCapital.Capital = B.agg
from TraderCapital as A JOIN TotalTable as B
ON A.Trader = B.Trader
AND A.Currency = B.Currency
AND A.Date = B.previousDay


with PreviousDayTable as (
select *, LAG(Date) over (partition by Trader, Currency order by Date) 
          as previousDay
from TraderCapital
)
delete A
from TraderCapital as A JOIN PreviousDayTable as B
ON A.Trader = B.Trader
AND A.Currency = B.Currency
AND A.Date = B.Date
where B.previousDay is not null
```

Feel free to suggest improvements.